# Northeastern or Northeast part?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say you were asked where the farmlands are, on a map. Which one is correct English that I can use?

> - The farmlands were situated in the northeast and southern part of the town.
> - The farmlands were situated in the northeast and **in** **the** southern part of the town.
> - The farmlands were situated in the northeast**ern** and **in** **the** southern part of the town.

Comment: What dialect of English are these examples written in?  In American English, a "township" can include extensive farmland, but a "town" usually refers to a built-up area of homes, businesses, and similar structures.

Comment: Maybe British...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't think any of these are suitable?

Comment: There are differences, which I think one entry from them is wrong grammatically.

Comment: @Jasper: in the U.S., the difference between a *town* and a *township* depends on the state and the technical designations it uses for political subdivisions. In Massachusetts, "towns" can be quite rural and include lots of farmland. In New Jersey, "towns" are usually much more urban than "townships". In California, I'm not sure the word "township" is used at all.

Comment: If you're pointing to a map, you should really use the word "are" and not "were" (unless this is an old map, and the farmland has been converted to subdivisions).

Comment: @PeterShor, I know the verb tense aspect, the time reference is in the past. Thx.

Comment: @PeterShor -- U.S. surveying has a grid of "townships" and "ranges".

Comment: @Jasper: the ***town*** of [Stow, MA](http://www.stowconservationtrust.org/land.php) contains significant tracts of farmland.

Comment: Both Pennsylvania and Michigan have **townships** with greater than 50,000 (even 100,000) people.

Comment: @Jasper Some US states, such as New York, use "town" to mean a geographic subdivision of  a county, which may contain one or more villages. Other US states, such as New Jersey and Michigan, use 'township" for this exact same legal concept. (I have been involved in local politics at the town/township level in all three states.) In none of these does "town"  or any similar word have the legal meaning of "a built-up area smaller than a city"  that is what "village" means in all three. Historically and informally, "town" does often mean something of the sort.

Comment: John Arvin, in Britain, we don't have farms in towns, except for little show farms called "city farms" in a few cities. Towns definitely don't contain "farmlands". Who wrote those examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of your three sentences, the third sentence is correct.

There is no grammatical requirement for suffix consistency (for it's own sake) in listing items in a sentence, so that doesn't clarify what is correct. That's more a question of writing style.

There is an [argument](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/east-or-eastern-north-or-northern) that the size of the region you're referring to dictates whether you use the "-ern" suffix. In that argument, "large" and "small" are arbitrary, so it's not clear whether both should have the "-ern" suffix or not, BUT if the two regions are roughly equal size, they should have the *same* suffix.

Whether you use "in the" or not is up to you - it doesn't make the sentence more or less correct.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to be consistent, so it is either situated in the northeast and the south, or the northeastern and southern part of something. Don't say the north and the southern, for example. In this case I think your third option is right, the other two are wrong.

Comment: I'd say “the south” and “the southern part” are synonyms, so the first two are guilty only of what Fowler called Elegant Variation: shunning repetition, at the cost of clarity or flow.  (I don't remember whether Fowler applied the concept to constructions as well as to words.)

Answer (score 0):

The third option is the best because it makes clear that the comparison is with the TOWN. The second is a more precise versions but makes global comparison indicating the 'northeast' of the COUNTRY, or the WORLD. The first is vague.

## ANALYSIS

FARMLANDS [subject] situated [VERB] northeastern and in the southern part [adjective] of the town [object].
Example 3 makes clear that 'northeastern and in the southern part' is one complex adjective linked to TOWN

Example 2 is 
FARMLANDS [subject] situated [VERB] northeast [OBJECT]  and in the southern part [adjective] of the town [ANOTHER OBJECT].

Comment: I don't understand this completely. I think you are missing some articles, pronouns and punctuations. Thx anyway

Comment: Agreed - I am missing some articles - I was just trying to highlight the relevant differences where the word choice lands up creating an implicit second object in the sentence.